# Performance Issue with Sorting Contacts Properties in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, sorting

I'm encountering a performance issue when attempting to sort contacts based on dynamic properties in MongoDB. Here's a simplified version of my schema:

```
const contactSchema = new Schema(
    {
        properties: [{
            _id: false,
            name: String,
            value: Schema.Types.Mixed,
            label: String
        }],
        source: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
        }],
        subaccount: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Subaccount"
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            enum: ["customer", "lead"]
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

Here we are using [Attribute Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern) for properties. Reason for this is that user can create dynamic contact properties.

like:

```
 properties: [
    { name: "email", value: "example@example.com", label: "Email Address" },
    { name: "age", value: 30, label: "Age" },
    { name: "custom_field", value: "custom_value", label: "Custom Field" }
    // ...more
  ]
```

Sample Contact Document

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "name_sp",
      "value": "Oliver Ebert"
    },
    {
      "name": "email_sp",
      "value": "Delphia_Gutmann@hotmail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "phone_sp",
      "value": "+918017380167"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ad_Budget_sp",
      "value": 33341
    },
    {
      "name": "city_sp",
      "value": "Minneapolis"
    },
    {
      "name": "country_sp",
      "value": "Djibouti"
    },
    {
      "name": "state_sp",
      "value": "Idaho"
    },
    {
      "name": "Team_Size_sp",
      "value": 199
    },
    {
      "name": "Revenue_sp",
      "value": 271627
    },
    {
      "name": "Enrolling_Date_sp",
      "value": {
        "$date": "2019-06-16T06:11:38.231Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "source": [
    {
      "$oid": "65f9b15d73e5ed0010b51008"
    }
  ],
  "subaccount": {
    "$oid": "63be5e5ed3e3860011909e9e"
  },
  "adhocProperties": [],
  "__v": 0,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-03-20T10:58:00.993Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-03-20T10:58:00.993Z"
  }
}
```

I've indexed **`subaccount`** and **`properties.value`** to optimise querying. However, when I attempt to sort the contacts based on a specific property (**`Team_Size_sp`** in this case), the query performance drastically deteriorates.

For instance, without sorting, the query returns results efficiently. But when sorting is applied, even with just 50 documents returned, it takes an extensive amount of time (e.g., 13 seconds) and examines a large number of index keys (e.g., almost 5 million).

I've tried various optimisations, including indexing and restructuring the query, but haven't found a satisfactory solution yet.

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on how to improve the performance of sorting contacts based on dynamic properties in MongoDB, especially considering a potentially large dataset (e.g., half a million contacts)?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

## Playground

This is the script which help you to create dummy contacts. so you can play around with it.

GitHub Repo : https://github.com/Royanosh/dummyContactsGenerator

I’m using node -v20

## Some Sample Queries And their Results

1. Getting 11th page based on subaccountId

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      subaccount: ObjectId(
        "63be5e5ed3e3860011909e9e"
      )
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      role: 1,
      source: 1,
      subaccount: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      updatedAt: 1,
      properties: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: "$properties",
              },
              0,
            ],
          },
          then: {
            k: "",
            v: "",
          },
          // Handle empty properties array
          else: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$properties",
                    cond: {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$this.name",
                            false,
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$this.value",
                            false,
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.name",
                  v: "$$this.value",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $skip: 500
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  },
]
```

### **Query Performance Summary**

- **50** documents returned
- **550** documents examined
- **3 ms** execution time
- **Is not** sorted in memory
- **550** index keys examined

  Query used the following index:

  **subaccount**

  **properties.value**

2. Applying Filter Like Country is India or Antarctica and Revenue is Greater than 12000 and getting 11th page

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      subaccount: ObjectId(
        "63be5e5ed3e3860011909e9e"
      ),
      properties: {
        $elemMatch: {
          name: "Revenue_sp",
          value: {
            $gt: 12000,
          },
        },
      },
      $or: [
        {
          properties: {
            $elemMatch: {
              name: "country_sp",
              value: "India",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          properties: {
            $elemMatch: {
              name: "country_sp",
              value: "Antarctica",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      role: 1,
      source: 1,
      subaccount: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      updatedAt: 1,
      properties: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: "$properties",
              },
              0,
            ],
          },
          then: {
            k: "",
            v: "",
          },
          // Handle empty properties array
          else: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$properties",
                    cond: {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$this.name",
                            false,
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$this.value",
                            false,
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.name",
                  v: "$$this.value",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $skip: 500
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  },
  
  
]
```

#### **Query Performance Summary**

- **50** documents returned
- **1108** documents examined
- **8 ms** execution time
- **Is not** sorted in memory
- **554** index keys examined

  Query used the following index:

  **subaccount**

  **properties.value**

3. Don’t applying any filters - only subaccountId, getting sorted docs based on Team Size and 11th page

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      subaccount: ObjectId(
        "63be5e5ed3e3860011909e9e"
      ),
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      role: 1,
      source: 1,
      subaccount: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      updatedAt: 1,
      properties: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: "$properties",
              },
              0,
            ],
          },
          then: {
            k: "",
            v: "",
          },
          // Handle empty properties array
          else: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$properties",
                    cond: {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$this.name",
                            false,
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$this.value",
                            false,
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.name",
                  v: "$$this.value",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "properties.Team_Size_sp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 500
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  },
  
  
]
```

#### **Query Performance Summary**

- **50** documents returned
- **500002** documents examined
- **13006 ms** execution time
- **Is not** sorted in memory
- **4999967** index keys examined

Query used the following index:

**subaccount**

**properties.value**

4. Applying Filter and sort like Country is India or Antarctica and Revenue is greater than 12000 and sorting based on Team Size

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      subaccount: ObjectId(
        "63be5e5ed3e3860011909e9e"
      ),
      properties: {
        $elemMatch: {
          name: "Revenue_sp",
          value: {
            $gt: 12000,
          },
        },
      },
      $or: [
        {
          properties: {
            $elemMatch: {
              name: "country_sp",
              value: "India",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          properties: {
            $elemMatch: {
              name: "country_sp",
              value: "Antarctica",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      role: 1,
      source: 1,
      subaccount: 1,
      createdAt: 1,
      updatedAt: 1,
      properties: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: "$properties",
              },
              0,
            ],
          },
          then: {
            k: "",
            v: "",
          },
          // Handle empty properties array
          else: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$properties",
                    cond: {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$this.name",
                            false,
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          $ifNull: [
                            "$$this.value",
                            false,
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.name",
                  v: "$$this.value",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "properties.Team_Size_sp": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 500
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  },
  
  
]
```

#### **Query Performance Summary**

- **50** documents returned
- **8086** documents examined
- **96 ms** execution time
- **Is not** sorted in memory
- **4043** index keys examined

Query used the following index:

**subaccount**

**properties.value**